# O que é CI/CD? Benefícios e riscos

Tags: engenharia-de-software, integração-contínua

É muito fácil encontrar a resposta para o conceito no Google mas queria entender como funciona na prática.

Sei que o **Amazon**, por exemplo, **migra código** pra produção a cada **poucos segundos**. Posso usar também em meu projeto pessoal? De forma direcional, tenho mais benefícios realizados do que trabalho pra implementar?

Comment: De uma olhada nesse artigo ele pode ser útil: https://lhlima.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/diferenca-entre-ci-integracao-continua-e-cd-distribuicao-continua/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Embora a pergunta seja clara sobre não ter muito interesse nos conceitos formais de CI e CD por estes serem facilmente encontrados no google eu achei bom dar uma introdução básica em ambos para deixar a resposta mais completa, mas caso você que está lendo já conheça ambos pode pular para a seção "Na prática".

### CI

Continuous integration propõe o seguinte: o projeto deve possuir um repositório central e todos os desenvolvedores devem enviar seu código para ele o mais frequentemente quanto possível, o que na prática quer dizer no máximo algumas horas. Ou seja, você fez uma pequena alteração no seu código e já envia ela para o repositório. É também necessário que exista um processo automático que é disparado a cada envio de código ao repositório central, esse processo deve checar erros do código integrado, vendo se as alteração funcionam corretamente em conjunto com o código alheio. Dessa forma problemas em implementações são encontrados automaticamente e de forma rápida, é apenas o tempo de você enviar seu código ao repositório e o processo de checagem rodar e relatar o resultado.

### CD

Continous delivery é você estabelecer um modelo de desenvolvimento que te permita fazer implantações rápidas e constantes quando necessário. Ao invés de produzir digamos uma versão do software pronta para produção a cada semana você produz várias delas (o tempo é relativo e varia conforme o contexto), o que permite, assim como em CI, acelerar a detecção de problemas e consequenetemente melhorar a confiabilidade do produto. Esse modelo desenvolvimento geralmente vem ancorado por um sistema de teste automatizados gerenciado por um sistema de integração contínua (CD difícilmente vai existir sem CI).

### Na prática

Quando comecei a trabalhar como dev alguns anos atrás uma das primeiras coisas que implementei na empresa em que estava foi uma sistema de integração contínua usando o [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), até a data desse post continuo lá e temos usado o sistema com muito sucesso. O esquema funciona assim: todos os projetos da empresa estão em diferentes repositórios do [subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/), a maioria dos projetos é em PHP e eles possuem suites de teste unitários em phpunit e de aceitação usando o selenium, todos os devs enviam código para o repositório com uma frequência de + - 1 commit a cada 15 minutos (fez algo, commita), a cada commit o jenkins dispara um processo (ou "build") que vai rodar todos os testes unitários e de aceitação em todo o sistema que agora contêm o novo código. Quando o jenkins termina de rodar a build ele publica internamente vários relatórios em formatos diversos dizendo o que é que rolou, o que está Ok e o que não. Por meio de uma integração com o chat da empresa o resultado e links desses relatórios são postados para todo mundo ver, ex:

[image: Links para relatórios de uma jenkins build]

Cada um dos links em azul é o relatório de uma ferramenta que foi rodada sobre o código do repositório, o link "Codeception" por exemplo é uma ferramenta que agrega os testes do phpunit e selenium, nessa build de exemplo o resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: Relatório de ferramentas de testes]

Como a foto mostra rolaram duas falhas de testes nessa execução, ou seja, algo enviado para o repositório está com problemas e deve ser revisto.

Com esse sistema de de integração contínua rola uma confiança muito maior na qualidade atual do software, se os relatórios indicam falha provavelmente tem algo errado (se os relatórios estarem ok indicam ou não que o software tem problemas vai depender muito das ferramentas que você usa e da qualidade dos seus testes, mas isso é outra história), podendo ver erros rapidamente o tempo gasto para corrigir eles é muito menor.

Essa confiança na qualidade corrente do software gerada pelo sistema de CI é também o que possibilita a aplicação de Continuous Delivery na empresa.
Para tal é usada uma mistura de [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) e [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) scripts, os quais, bem resumidamente, foram configurados para tornar o processo de colocar uma nova versão de um dos softwares em produção simplesmente rodar um comando parecido com `bash deploy-script.bash [nome do projeto]`, o que torna tudo bastante fácil (exceto quando um desses script quebra, heh) e permite diversos deploys diários quando necessário.

### Vale pena?

Os benefícios espero que já tenham ficado claros: feedback constante do estado do software, velocidade na detecção de bugs, elevação de confiabilidade no produto, velocidade maior em implantar novas versões em prdução, etc. Obviamente isso tudo não vem de graça, CI e CD exigem um certo trabalho, tanto de aprendizado como de implementação, fora o tempo gasto com manutenção. O "risco" de aplicar essa práticas é o tempo que vai ser gasto construíndo, configurando e mantendo as ferramentas e códigos necessários.

Se vale a pena ou não e se vai compensar o tempo gasto montando a arquitetura é algo que só pode ser respondido com uma boa contextualização de o que está sendo feito e por quem está sendo feito. Ou seja, depende ;(. Mas como regra geral eu diria que se for possível implantar um sistema de CI e CD, implante, pois provavelmente vai te salvar um bom tempo e dores de cabeça no médio/longo prazo.

Comment: Olá, @BrunoRB! Depois de mais de um ano, você tem algo a acrescentar ou melhorar na sua resposta. Tenho muito interesse em ouvir mais de você sobre esse tema. Obrigado!

Comment: @LaFlame tenho sim umas experiências novas para compartilhar.
Dia de semana é complicado, então provavelmente lá pelo sabádo eu dou um up na resposta.

Answer (score 13):

Posso falar um pouco da minha experiência no meu local de trabalho. Resumo a priori: estamos trabalhando para tentar começar uma CI confiável para, então, termos uma CD para **entregar valor ao cliente** o mais cedo possível.

### História de ciclo de desenvolvimento

Em 2013, onde eu trabalho atualmente, usava um único VCS de geração 2 (SVN mesmo; para nomenclatura, [vide Eric Sink](http://ericsink.com/vcbe/html/history_of_version_control.html)) para guardar os fontes Java; tínhamos 2 produtos que, em teoria, deveriam desempenhar o mesmo conjunto de funções: um projeto para dispositivo móvel (TotalCross) e outro para portal de gerenciamento (GWT). No final das contas (incluindo hábitos dessa geração e cultura da empresa), isso significava que alterações de códigos para inovações (adições de features, experimentos, etc) e manutenções (correções de bugs e melhorias de performance) eram feitas no mesmo *branch*. No fim das contas, isso significava que:

1. o desenvolvedor trabalhava num esquema de código `V1`;
2. quando tinha conflito, quem ganhava no final das contas era quem deixava para entregar o trabalho por último, sobrescrevendo o código de quem quer que tenha mexido concorrentemente;
3. no final das contas, o que era commitado de fato era o código `v2` (após resolver os conflitos);
4. era feito o build do código `v3` para teste;
5. o teste encontra uma falha em `v3`, mas o desenvolvedor que pega essa falha já está em `v5` (!!!!);
6. a correção é feita e se entrega `v6`;
7. faz-se o build de teste `v7` para teste;
8. teste aprova `v7`, então é feito o build `v8` para produção;
9. `v8` apresenta problemas óbvios em produção que `v7` não apresentava;
10. viram-se noites com o código `v12` para produzir uma `v13` final;
11. `v13` corrige todos os problemas de `v8`, mas aí um cliente detecta uma regressão em relação ao que ele estava usando;
12. pega-se `v17` e tenta corrigir rapidamente, produzindo uma `v18`;
13. o testador pega o build de testes `v21` e aponta outros problemas de regressão;
14. pega-se o código em `v30` e corrige-se esses problemas, gerando a versão de testes `v31`;
15. o testador homologa o build de `v32`;
16. os clientes homologam o build de `v37`;
17. vai para produção o build de `v42` (!!!).

Sim, esse era o tamanho do trauma para se lançar versões... No final, um ciclo de lançamento de novas funcionalidades era de 6 a 8 meses, então chegava uma caixa misteriosa que o cliente tentava usar.

Isso começou a mudar em setembro de 2014, quando aconteceram as seguintes mudanças:

1. mavenização dos projetos;
2. mudança para um VCS de geração 3 (git);
3. adoção de uma variação do [GitFlow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/);
4. todo código só entra no `master` ou `develop` após revisão (via *merge request*);
5. gerenciamento visual através de um portal web (GitLab CE).

Isso evitou ter o caos de manutenção em produção, permitindo agora que os desenvolvedores passassem a ter noites de sono. O que o testador homologa agora é o mesmo build que o cliente homologa e usa em produção. Também, devido ao ambiente de homologação, os erros eram capturados numa sandbox muito mais segura. Essa quebra de paradigma (de **código único** para **código estável** / `master` e **código instável** / `develop`) melhorou nossa qualidade de código e estabilidade de novas versões, porém não ajudou na velocidade de lançamento.

Mesmo com as constantes revisões de códigos, acontecia de o build quebrar após a aceitação de um ou outro *merge request*; os motivos eram realmente aleatórios, mas enfim... Então, o primeiro passo em direção à CI foi dado: toda criação de um *merge request* resulta na execução automática do build para o resultado do merge. Isso detectou muitos problemas relativos a isso, poupando o tempo do revisor e do abençoado que iria corrigir isso.

No final de 2014, foi detectado que boa parte dos problemas encontrados no código do portal era de funcionalidades idênticas às do código do móvel; então, em maio 2015, foi feita a unificação das bases de código, criando o coração do sistema que precisava de duas carcaças: UI e acesso ao banco. No caso, o menor esforço que tínhamos para alcançar essa unificação era a aplicação injetar as dependências de banco no coração, enquanto que a UI se encarregava de chamar o coração para fazer os encaminhamentos certos. Após um período de estabilização decorrente dessa mudança de arquitetura (algo entre julho e outubro de 2015), conseguimos lançar versões de 3 em 3 meses.  Boa parte do atraso técnico do portal (features não implementadas e bugs corrigidos no móvel) foi corrigido com isso, sendo portanto o foco das atenções agora funcionalidades nova e performance.

Ainda assim, estávamos aquém do nosso objetivo de velocidade: uma versão final fechada e testada por semana (ainda não chega a ser CD, mas quase lá). Razão da nossa lentidão? Regressão. O que precisávamos para impedir regressão? Teste. Porém, contratar pessoal de teste para fazer coisas tolas e repetitivas para toda versão lançada é muito desperdício de dinheiro. A solução viável? Testes automatizados.

Os testes automatizados começaram a ser escritos em agosto de 2015, porém a criação desses testes só conseguiu ganhar tração em julho de 2016. Em outubro de 2016, passamos a colocar que um *merge request* só seria aceito se tivesse teste automático. Isso servia para diversos motivos:

- se o *merge request* fosse um `hotfix`, acontecia a prova de que o código de produção estava errado;
- garante que uma feature nova se comporta bem para alguns cenários previstos/comuns;
- evita a simples existência de regressão.

Desde o momento que ganhou tração (em julho de 2016) até o fim do mês de março deste ano (2017), os testes automatizados não trouxeram o aumento da velocidade na liberação, porém deu maior credibilidade às builds. A partir de 10 de abril, então, estamos no ritmo de 1 versão para cada duas semanas, com cada vez maior estabilidade a cada versão.

### Conclusão

Bem, estamos deixando cada vez mais suave o desenvolvimento dos nossos softwares (móvel, portal e coração). Quando o desenvolvimento alcança uma suavidade muito grande, então obtemos a integração contínua. Os objetivos de ter uma integração contínua, no nosso contexto, são dois:

1. valorizar o software (sob o ponto de vista do cliente) mais rapidamente;
2. garantir que o que funciona antes continua funcionando.

Com a integração contínua, podemos passar para um próximo estágio: entregar continuamente ao cliente valor.

Não estamos numa corrida para por CD simplesmente porque CD é bonito, porque está na moda. Imagina ter uma entrega contínua com o fluxo de entrega descrito logo no começo? Entrega contínua deve visar o cliente e deve ser feito de forma responsável. Não pretendemos perder cliente porque cada lançamento bissemanal quebra tudo que havia anteriormente; reconheço que as vezes irritamos os clientes quando mudamos o visual ou deixamos a navegação mais fluida/intuitiva, porque ele já estava acostumado com o esquema antigo, mas não os perdemos pelo menos =)

O maior risco que CD pode ocasionar é falhar no segundo objetivo descrito acima: **garantir que o que funciona antes continua funcionando**. Uma CD feita de maneira irresponsável não garante essa estabilidade.

O risco imposto por CI é infinitamente menor do que o imposto por CD, porém é muito grande quando comparado a uma integração mais lenta. Basicamente, uma CI irresponsável pode atrapalhar o primeiro objetivo descrito acima: **valorizar o software (sob o ponto de vista do cliente) mais rapidamente**, pois o *branch* com o **código instável** `develop` será mais instável do que o desejável, ocasionando num *lead time* maior entre o começo do desenvolvimento duma funcionalidade nova até a real entrega dessa funcionalidade.