# O que são "stages" e "jobs" no contexto do GitLabCI?

Tags: integração-contínua, gitlab

Vendo aqui a opção de [botar o CI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202466/64969) no GitLab (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html). Fiquei em dúvida sobre a nomenclatura que eles usam.

Eles dizem que tudo roda em uma *pipeline* (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html), e que isso é a "linha de montagem" do meu software. Essa *pipeline*, por sua vez, é dividida em *stages* e *jobs*.

- O que são *stages*?
- O que são *jobs*?

Relacionado:

- [O que é Travis CI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197689/64969)
- [O que é CI/CD? Benefícios e riscos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202466/64969)

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202466/5878

Comment: Provavelmente também vale citar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197689/5878

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , linkei diretamente. Vou tentar colocar em cantos perdidos do texto também para melhorar a ligação dos assuntos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*stages* são, digamos assim, "rótulos" gerais. Um estágio só começa quando o estágio anterior termina. Dentro de um mesmo estágio, entretanto, diversos *jobs* distintos podem ser executados em paralelos.

Tome, por exemplo, o seguinte *pipeline*:

[image: 3 stages e 4 jos]

Ele tem 3 estágios, em ordem:

1. `build-test-nucleo`
2. `build-apps`
3. `test-apps`

Por sua vez, eles são divididos nos seguintes *jobs*:

1. `build-test-nucleo`

   - `build-nucleo`
2. `build-apps`

   - `build-mobile`
   - `build-portal`
3. `test-apps`

   - `test-mobile`

Na imagem fica bem claro a relação de dependência de execução. Internamente, o que acontece:

1. um *runner* levanta um *container* para realizar o *job* `build-nucleo`; quando termina guarda um [*cache*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#cache) (se houver)
2. quando o estágio anterior terminar, o seguinte vai ocorrer em paralelo:

   - um *runner* levanta outro *container* para realizar o *job* `build-mobile`; também guardará *cache* caso haja
   - um outro *runner* levanta mais um *container* para realizar o *job* `build-portal`; também guardará *cache* caso haja
3. quando os dois *jobs* do estágio anterior terminarem, o *job* `test-mobile` será chamado.

Como o *cache* só é aproveitado dentro da mesma *pipeline*, compartilhado por *jobs*, o `test-mobile` poderá até guardar um *cache*, mas isso não terá efeitos práticos.

A seguir, excertos significativos do `.gitlab-ci.yml` que resultam nesse *pipeline*:

```yaml
stages:
  - build-test-nucleo
  - build-apps
  - test-apps

cache:
  - .m2
  - '*/target'

build-test-nucleo:
  stage: build-test-nucleo
  script:
    - cd nucleo
    - mvn compile test
    - cd ..

build-mobile:
  stage: build-apps
  script:
    - cd mobile
    - mvn compile
    - cd ..
  dependencies:
    - build-nucleo

build-portal:
  stage: build-apps
  script:
    - cd portal
    - mvn compile
    - cd ..
  dependencies:
    - build-nucleo

test-mobile:
  stage: test-apps
  script:
    - cd mobile
    - mvn test
    - cd ..
  dependencies:
    - build-mobile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - mobile/*.dump*
      - mobile/target/
    when: on_failure
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Explicando:

Primeiro, eu quis usar os meus *stages*, não os *stages* padrão. Se nada for definido, o GitLab se comporta como se existissem esses *stages* ([fonte](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages)):

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
```

Essa *pipeline* de 3 estágios já me atendeu ao fazer *builds* de bibliotecas, mas eu precisava de algo mais agora. A ideia é continuar com mais estágios e por todos os passos do *build* aqui, mas estou trabalhando com calma.

Depois eu especifico o *cache* que vai ser compartilhado com os *jobs*. Eu precisei usar `'*/target'` protegido por aspas simples para evitar que o YAML tivesse interpretação especial.

> Nota: se você definir um *cache* dentro do *job*, ele sobrescreverá a definição do *cache*. Não haverá *merge*! Isso já me deu dor de cabeça.

Após essas duas definições, vou atrás de montar meus *jobs*. Cada *job* precisa indicar seu *stage* e ter um script de execução. O script é a linha de comando mesmo, sem segredos. Pode abusar do *bash* caso sua máquina de build seja Linux =)

Eu fiz questão de colocar que um *job* depende do outro para ser executado, pois, isso me dá uma liberdade maior para por condicionais de execução de algum *job* e evitar que *jobs* conseguintes sejam executados. A ideia é que quando eu terminar, exista um *job* de empacotamento automático para o portal e o mobile que seja executado apenas ao subir uma *tag*, para então ter o *job* manual para por o executável em teste.

No caso do *job* de teste, eu mandei que ele arquivasse arquivos:

```yaml
artifacts:
  paths:
    - mobile/*.dump*
    - mobile/target/
  when: on_failure
  expire_in: 1 week
```

No caso, estou arquivando apenas quando há falhas no *build* (`when: on_failure`). Como são resultados para inspeção de bugs em testes automatizados, não me interessa que eles fiquem muito tempo no ar, então pus tempo de expiração de 1 semana (`expire_in: 1 week`). Os arquivos para serem arquivados ou estão dentro de `mobile/target`, ou então combinam com o glob `mobile/*.dump*`.