# Como trabalhar de forma eficiente com branch no git?

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando definir um esquema de trabalho para manter meu repositório no **GitHub** organizado, mas tá difícil chegar a uma solução.

Minha "ideia":

Pensei em manter no repositório remoto os branch **master** (default) e **develop**. **O branch *master* será bloqueado**, somente aceitará merge após revisão do pull-request, ou seja, os colaboradores irão enviar suas contribuições para o **develop** e gerar um pull request deste para o master.

Os branch feature/xpto, hotfix/xpto e outros serão ramificados a partir do **develop**, não sei se seria interessante ramificar ainda mais com uso de branch **topic**. *Antes de efetuar o merge dos branch locais com **develop**, deve ser avaliada a necessidade de aplicar um rebase full ou de alguns commit, tendo como objetivo manter uma linha histórica limpa e fácil de ser lida*, após o merge local e o push para o remote, no GitHub deverá ser gerado um pull-request do `master <- develop`.

No texto assim já foi possível observar algumas dúvidas, vamos consolidar elas e mais algumas:

- Na prática branch topic são realmente úteis e utilizados?
- O rebase local antes do push é uma boa ideia, em que situação seria aconselhável?
- Seria mais aconselhável alterar meu arquivo CHANGELOG.md no branch de develop, ou criar um branch release, alterar lá e depois fazer o merge com `master` e `develop`?
- Ao realizar um merge de `master` <- `develop`, devo utilizar o merge request (que leva todos os commit + 1 de merge), ou um merge squash (que gera somente 1 commit de saída)? Porque da sua sugestão?

Devido a importância do próximo tópico, resolvi separar o mesmo dos anteriores:

Quando vou realizar um pull-request do `master` <- `develop` um conflito em sempre irá ocorrer, este é referente ao arquivo **CHANGELOG.md**, considerando que novos dados sempre são inseridos na parte superior, o git sempre acusará uma alteração para a qual um merge automático não pode ser executado. Como resolver esse problema?

Possíveis soluções:

- No caso do GitHub este sugere fazer um merge do `develop` <- `master`, resolver o conflito, aplicar o commit de controle e concluir o pull-request/merge;
- Crio uma branch de release a partir de `develop`, faço o merge de `release\xxx` <- `master`, resolvo os conflitos, aplico o devido commit, realizo o merge de `master` <- `release\xxx` e `develop` <- `release\xxx`;
- Ou teria outra abordagem "melhor"? Por melhor me refiro a abordagens utilizadas pela comunidade para projetos colaborativos, que comprovadamente são mas eficientes.

---

Dúvidas finais:

Ao seguir a esteira do ***git flow***, após a criação do branch **release**, devo fazer merge deste com o mater e develop, considerando que meu **master** encontra-se protegido no GitHub (aceitando merge só via pull request), devo subir este branch para o remote e gerar o pull-request para o master? E para o develop, faço o merge local e aplico um push?

*Obs: Acredito que essa dúvida faça parte da cabeça de muita gente.*

Comment: Dica: não ramifique `hotfix` do `develop`. Se é quente está em produção, portanto ramifica do `master`. Pode até ser que o **pull request** seja feito por alguém menos experiente no `develop`, mas tentar ramificar dele é bem complicado. Eu tratei alguma coisa sobre branches e tags [numa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275914/64969). Mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204408/64969)

Comment: Gitflow faz tudo isso proce =)

Comment: Não entendi porque CHANGELOG.md gera conflito pelos dados estarem na parte superior do arquivo

Comment: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.pt_BR.html

Comment: https://medium.com/trainingcenter/utilizando-o-fluxo-git-flow-e63d5e0d5e04

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo além de `git checkout master && git merge release/v1.0.1` ainda deve ser feito o merge com develop, correto? Outra dúvida, ele faz o merge local, isso seria equivalente a eu ir para o master e fazer um pull (considerando que o master já esta atualizado)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho o GitFlow uma abordagem eficiente e organizada, abaixo segue um link e imagem para ilustrar melhor:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Compreendi, mas algumas dúvidas ainda continuam pairando no ar. Por exemplo: após gerar o branch release, o merge deste tem que ser feito no master e no develop, considere que meu master esta protegido, só aceita pull-request. Sendo assim seria adequado fazer o merge no develop e um pull-request no master? Qual a real esteira em um projeto real?

Comment: O branch release é criado a partir da develop e utlizo para alterações finais no período de homologação, por exemplo. Este branch só sera mergeado com a master para o deploy em produção.

Comment: Todas as dúvidas aos poucos foram se resolvendo, entretanto, hoje surgiu a seguinte questão: por qual motivo eu faço o merge do branch de release no master e depois no develop, não seria mais adequado depois do merge no master, simplesmente fazer um merge --ff no develop para ter algo como `commit xxx (HEAD -> develop, tag: v1.0.0, master)`?

Comment: Você pode ter pequenas alterações apartir do momento que você gerou o branch release, quando de fato vc finalizar a release e for fazer a virada para produção, vc irá atualizar o master que representa produção e o develop que ainda não foi contemplado com estas pequenas alterações.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, já que muitas das dúvidas continuaram martelando em minha cabeça, resolvi estudar o assunto um pouco mas a fundo. Considerando o conhecimento adquirido, tentarei responder as questões que antes representavam dúvidas absolutas:

- Na prática, branch topic são realmente úteis e utilizados?

> Branch topic podem ser utilizado para ter um maior controle de fluxos "longos" de dessenvolimento. Funcionalidades que geram muitas etapas podem ser divididas em branch topic, com isso uma linha do tempo mais detalhada pode permitir regressões parciais mais controladas; Neste caso citado os branch topic se mostram relevantes (úteis), logo é um ótimo cenário para utilizar essa abordagem.

- O rebase local antes do push é uma boa ideia, em que situação seria aconselhável?

> Sim, é valido para alterações que ainda não foram empurradas para o repositório remoto. As situações podem ser as mais *diversas possíveis*, como um commit para alterar um comentário incorreto no código, corrigir um erro que não deveria esta presente no commit anterior, tal como esquecer um delimitador de linha, entre outros. Em resumo, principalmente quando geramos algum commit desnecessário, mas utilize este recurso com sabedoria, tente não fazer rebase se já tiver empurrado o commit para o remote.

- Seria mas aconselhável alterar meu arquivo CHANGELOG.md no branch de develop, ou criar um branch release, alterar lá e depois fazer o merge no `master` e `develop`?

> Preferencialmente no branch release, este é um ramo criado para preparar o lançamento de uma nova versão... Diante disso, neste branch podemos consolidar um CHANGELOG já com as devidas referências para os commit que contêm as alterações ali citadas, alterar dados no README ou realizar outras pequenas adequações.

- Ao realizar um merge de `master` <- `develop`, devo utilizar o merge request (que leva todos os commit + 1 de merge), ou um merge squash (que gera somente 1 commit de saída)? Porque da sua sugestão?

> O merge request na minha opinião permite maior rastreabilidade, controle e legibilidade do histórico

Dúvidas finais:

- Ao seguir a esteira do ***git flow***, após a criação do branch **release**, devo fazer merge deste com o mater e develop, considerando que meu **master** encontra-se protegido no GitHub (aceitando merge só via pull request), devo subir este branch para o remote e gerar o pull-request para o master? E para o develop, faço o merge local e aplico um push?

> Depende. Se o bloqueio no master tiver liberado para colaboradores ou Admins, o merge para o master pode ser feito local e na sequência realizado push. Caso esteja bloqueado até para Admins, pode ser gerado um pull request de um branch de release para o master, ou até mesmo a partir do próprio develop.

*Seguir workflows como o git-flow é algo interessante e muito válido, porém, é bom ter em mente que cada projeto possui características e abordagens próprias, diante disso é necessário modificar os processos de gerenciamento sempre que se fizerem necessário.*